# Java: Count number of bits set in a java.util.BitSet

Tags: java, bitset

Any quick method to count the number of set bits in a BitSet other than the usual 'keep a counter' method?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The [cardinality()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#cardinality()) method returns the number of set bits.

Comment: If you were wondering how this is implemented: It does not keep an internal counter, it loops over the `long[]` that is used to hold the bits and calls `Long#bitCount` for each of them.

Comment: under the covers it uses Long.bitCount(). On modern CPU's there is a CPU instruction for this, popcnt.       

In recent versions of Java, Long.bitCount() uses this instruction.       Just use -XX:+UsePopCountInstruction to turn it on   (this is the default in recent versions of Java)

Answer (score 3):

(Assuming you don't want to call cardinality())

```
int count = 0; 
for (int i = bs.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0; i = bs.nextSetBit(i+1)) {
    count++;
}
```

[see javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#nextSetBit%28int%29)

Answer (score 1):

```
BitSet B1 = new BitSet(3);
B1.set(0);
B1.cardinality();
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: This doesn't really add much beyond the answer referring to this method posted 6 years ago.

Comment: I disagree with @Dukeling. One - it uses BitSet's API. Two - it's one method call, not 4 lines with a loop. This is the correct answer IMO, previous answer is a brute force approach.

Comment: @vacant78 I was referring to [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4883196/1711796), which references the same method, with a link to the docs and a brief explanation of what it does.

Comment: @Dukeling - clearly, I had a bad moment there, unable to see the best (and highest voted) answer... my mistake.